# Is there a way to create an animated video texture based on uv layout?

Tags: texturing, uv, video, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

what I'm trying to do is to make a video animation in After Effects and then apply it on a 3D object as a texture. I'm trying to animate a circle movement over the faces of a cube based on its uv map (see video below; arrows tracks the circle movement) but the problem is that I can't figure out how to manage the circle animation on consecutive faces which aren't connected.

Can anyone help me? Is there a way or strategy in order to do this in a simple way?

Thanks to everyone!

[image]

Comment: It seems that there's something in this video which is very close to what i'm looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrnDr9_xBqM

Comment: This stack exchange is for Blender, not for Adobe AE. Although I do not know a single thing about After Effects, one solution might be to make another circle, place it on the other side of the unconnected face, and have it move in as the other circle moves out. But then again, the Blender StackExchange is not a place for such questions and you should move this to another location.

Comment: You can do this with UV project modifier. Use an empty to project the texture. Then animate the empty so that the texture moves where you want it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about using Blender